# How to set a variable activeMonth sheet name by cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building an AppScript and trying to call a sheet dynamically, each sheet is named Month YYYY in that format.  I will always need to call the previous month's sheet so I have a Defaults page and a formula in a cell that has the name of the tab I need but I don't know how to set name of sheet by the cell.

var activeMonth = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Defaults!'A2) is the general idea.

Anyone know how to do this?

I tried to use a cell reference but that didn't work.

Comment: Is month January, Jan, 01, or 1 or even o in the case of the javascript Date Object Month is not very helpful.  We don't  know what's inside of your head.  What you mean I tried to use a cell reference.  Please provide examples.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to retrieve the contents of Defaults!A2.

```
let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
let sheet = spread.getSheetByName('Defaults!');
let activeMonth = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
sheet = spread.getSheetByName(activeMonth);
```

Reference

- [Spreadsheet.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet())
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))
- [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

Comment: It's not the contents of Defaults I need, it's the contents of a sheet called "March 2024" but when I run it next the sheet I'll need is "April 2024", but the cell A2 in Defaults has the name of tab so I want to call the sheet with the name of A2 on the Defaults tab, if that makes sense?

Comment: I've edited my script to get the sheet whose name is in Defaults!A2